# gcc, makefile does not link correctly

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have this makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -c -Wall -std=c99 -ggdb

all: plan

plan: plan.o graph.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) plan.o graph.o -o plan

plan.o: plan.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) plan.c

graph.o: graph.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) graph.c

run: all
    ./plan
```

when I run make, gcc give me the message "linker input file unused because linking not done", what does it mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option means:

> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.

You should not use that option when building.

See [gcc man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

#### Update

For the *plan* target, do not use the CFLAGS:

```
plan: plan.o graph.o
    $(CC) -Wall -std=c99 -ggdb plan.o graph.o -o plan
```

Comment: so, I should simply remove the -c flag from CFLAGS and it will work?

Comment: Not really. you need the `-c` to compile your `.c` files. You just don't need this option when you are building the *plan* target. I'll update the answer now..